# what does notation Q(z|X) really mean?

Tags: probability

I am not a math guy, but I would say it means a probability of z given X. Or to be more simplistic, it means what is the likelihood of event z happen when considering an event X has already happened. The conditional probability of course.

But in machine learning and neural networks, I often see people use term Q(z|X) to for probability distribution. Why is this? To me, nonmath guy, this is completely confusing.

Is there any logic behind, why this term is used in machine learning and neural nets, couldn't they came up with some new term to describe probability distribution?

Comment: Often used as a shorthand for the family of conditional probabilities $P(Z=z\mid X=x)$, indexed by every possible $(x,z)$, for some given random variables $X$ and $Z$. Not rigorous. In the present case, one can wonder why they do not use $Q(z\mid x)$ or $Q(Z\mid X)$, to the same effect.

Comment: Any examples???